# how to css absolute positioning right way

Tags: html, css

I am mess with css position and can some one to help me. I need to moved off the screen child div from document (window) , adding some margin to `x-wrap` element.

when i add `margin-right` child is always in right side of document. please check my below screen shot.

**HTML**

```
<div class="x-wrap">
    <div class="x">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.x-wrap{
    margin-right: 8800px;
}
.x{
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

[image]

When i add minus `margin-left` in to the `x-wrap`. It is woking as what i need. blue child box is moved off the screen.

```
.x-wrap{
    margin-left: -800px;
}
```

[image]

=========================================================================

***I really need to know reson for that.***
Thank You ver much !

=========================================================================

Comment: The box is not hidden actually..it is moved off the screen...

Comment: @gopinathKoothaperumal Yes !.. sorry i need to moved off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to know what's happening, huh?

**absolute** positioning aligns the element "on top of" the parent who has a **relative** position.

So, placing your square like:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
|XXXXX|                       |
|XXXXX|                       | <--- parent element with relative positioning
|XXXXX+-----------------------+
+-----+
   \
    \
     --- child element with absolute positioning
```

When you declare an **absolute** child, it will automatically align its top left corner with its relative parent's top left corner by default.

---

Hence, in your css, you re-enforce this (in case your anchor position is different/etc) using:

```
left:0;
top:0;
```

---

So let's look at the bigger picture:

```
       +---------------------------------------------------+
       |                                                   |
       |+-----+-----------------------+                    |
       ||XXXXX|                       |                    |
       ||XXXXX|                       |                    |
       ||XXXXX+-----------------------+                    |
       |+-----+                                            |
       |<200px>                                            |
       |                                                   |<-- screen
       |                                                   |
       |                                                   |
       |                                                   |
       +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Since setting **margins** to 0, (as well as padding), it means your divs will align to the side of your screen, as shown above.

---

By setting a **negative left-margin** of 200px on our parent, it means our parent 'moves' to the left (and hence off screen):

```
       +---------------------------------------------------+
       |                                                   |
 +-----+-----------------------+                           |
 |XXXXX|                       |                           |
 |XXXXX|                       |                           |
 |XXXXX+-----------------------+                           |
 +-----+             <-- parent is pushed to left using    |
       |                 a left margin of -200px           |
       |                                                   |<-- screen
       |                                                   |
       |                                                   |
       |                                                   |
       +---------------------------------------------------+
```

so there you have it: Hopefully you can see now why this child div (when its relative parent is given a negative margin) why it isn't seen on screen.

---

Furthermore, setting any of the

```
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

on any absolutely positioned element will align it to that 'side/edge' of the relative parent's 'side/edge'

---

- **[Follow up reading](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)**

---

Comment: any other clarifications/situations you want explained?

Answer (score 0):

`Margin-left` moves the `div` left side which is hidden and `margin-right` gives `margin` to `right` you will get to know `margin-right` by adding and `element` it will move the new `element` right

you can also move the `div` `left` by changing `left` value the default property of `absolute` element is `left:0` `top:0`

if you really want to hide the div then use `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` or `display:none`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually need to know reason margin-left and margin-right with DOM :)

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left` will add px's to left (pushing the element to the right), `margin-right` will add px's to the right (pushing the element to the left). The point of `margin` is to push the element away from it's surroundings. So adding a lot of `margin` will push that element in whatever direction you tell it to.

Since you are using `position: absolute` what you really want to do is use the `left` and `right` properties to move the element. You can even use negative pixels to move the element off screen, such as `left: -100px`.

Here is an example in which I removed the `margin` from `.x-wrap` and added `left: -200px` to `.child`. As you can see the blue box is off screen now:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ug5qcy0e/)